# dúvida condições de Linq to Sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Tenho uma GridView com determinados produtos e uma DropDown de quantidade para cada.
Num evento `onClick`, são recuperados os produtos com quantidade > 0.

O problema é quando eu tenho uma tabela "detalhesPedido", e invoco ela com Linq to SQL. Meu objetivo era comparar se ela tem o item em questão. Caso tenha, adiciona apenas a quantidade. Caso não, acresenta o item quadtidade e preço.

Segue o código:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    // Pegando os produtos
    Label lblProdutoID = row.FindControl("lblProdutoID") as Label;
    var preco = (from p in db.Produtos
                 where p.ProdutoID == Convert.ToInt32(lblProdutoID.Text)
                 select p.Preco).SingleOrDefault();

    var produto = (from p in db.Produtos
                 where p.ProdutoID == Convert.ToInt32(lblProdutoID.Text)
                 select p).SingleOrDefault();

    int dropDownListText = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlQtde")).SelectedItem.Value);

    if ((dropDownListText != 0))
    {
        // aqui pegamos os produtos caso tenha no detalhes do pedido
        var nte = (from p in db.DetalhesPedidos
                   where p.PedidoID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["pedido"])
                   where p.ProdutoID == Convert.ToInt32(lblProdutoID.Text)
                   select p).SingleOrDefault();

        if (nte == null)
        {
            DetalhesPedido dp = new DetalhesPedido
            {
                UsuarioID = usurioid,
                PedidoID = novopedido.PedidoID,
                ProdutoID = produto.ProdutoID,
                Qtde = Convert.ToInt32(dropDownListText),
                Preco = Convert.ToDecimal(produto.Preco),
                Total = Convert.ToDecimal(produto.Preco * Convert.ToDecimal(dropDownListText)),
            };

            db.DetalhesPedidos.InsertOnSubmit(dp);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else if (nte.ProdutoID == produto.ProdutoID)
        {
            nte.Qtde += dropDownListText;
            nte.Total = produto.Preco * nte.Qtde;
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E o que exatamente está acontecendo que não está de acordo?

Comment: Faltou mais esclarecimento da sua dificuldade.